# How can I find .bacpac files in my Azure subscription inside storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, bacpac

We have a subscription in Azure that has a SQL Server and all databases are being backed up once a month.

We would like to download those backups but we cannot find or we don't know where can we find the `.bacpac` files, is there a way to find them or scan in the subscription to find them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this using the long term retention backups in Azure SQL?

Comment: A `.bacpac` is generated when creating a data-tier application, which takes a copy of the database schema and data for deployment elsewhere; it's not, strictly speaking, a backup. Backups will be stored as the `.bak` file type (for FULL and DIFF) backups, and `.trn` for transaction log backups.

@juunas has the right question though, _how_ are the databases being backed up? Is this Azure SQL, Azure SQL Managed Instance, or an Azure VM with SQL Server installed? What tool are you using to perform the backups?